# same table same field with same field conditions - Possible? in one sql

Tags: sql

here is my query i want to execute it as

```
$query="select * from $post INNER JOIN  $postmeta on $postmeta.post_id= $post.ID 
where $post .post_status='publish' 
and  $post .post_type ='task 
and $post .post_type='service' 
ORDER BY $post .post_date DESC ";
```

how to execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous a proper sanitize of the var $postmeta and $post you can do this way 
Building dinamic query by string concantenation  (because var in tabel and column name are not allowed in sql)

```
$query="select * from "  . $post  . " INNER JOIN  "  . 
        $postmeta  . " on  "   . $postmeta . ".post_id= " . $post .".ID   where " . 
        $post . ".post_status='publish' and  " . $post .".post_type ='task' and " . 
        $post . "post_type='service' ORDER BY " . $post .".post_date DESC ";
```